# How to add extra tag in rss feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed

I have implemented rss feed for my site.Took help from http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-easily-make-your-own-rss-feed/

Now it shows only title and description in feed page.But i want to show more info like property location and property type.So i have used

```
<location>
<![CDATA[ example ]]>
</location>
<property_type>
<![CDATA[ example]]>
</property_type>
```

I have used it inside the item tag.But on feed page it doesn't shows but after pressing ctrl+u i can see the xml code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invent your own elements (that aren't part of RSS) and expect an RSS client to do anything with them.

If you want to display additional content in a generic RSS client, you need to write it in HTML and make it part of the regular content.